# Does anybody know a plugin to bundling js/css files in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, bundling-and-minification

The available JS/Css Plugin can only minify files so far.
Is there any work-a-around to create bundled files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans 8.0 comes with GruntJS support, that's probably the best way (install GruntJS and run tasks from NetBeans). There's a lot of things one can do with Grunt, not only combining/minifation